# Как склоняется фамилия Басюкайтис?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Как склоняется фамилия Басюкайтис

Answer (score 4):

Как правило, подобные фамилии склоняются также как остальные слова 2 склонения, если речь идёт о мужчине, т.е. *Басюкайтис-Басюкайтиса-Басюкайтиса-Басюкайтису-Басюкайтисом-о Басюкайтисе*. Если же фамилия принадлежит женщине, то слово не склоняется, только *Басюкайтис*.

Answer (score 1):

Фамилия Басюкайтис не может принадлежать женщине. Если женщина жена Басюкайтиса - она Басюкайтене, если дочь - Басюкайте

Comment: Фамилия Басюкайтис не может принадлежать женщине. Если женщина жена Басюкайтиса - она Басюкайтене, если дочь - Басюкайте

Comment: Простите, Вы литовец?  

>Фамилия Басюкайтис не может принадлежать женщине.   
  
В литовском. А в русском - Вполне может. Вышла русская девушка за литовца, расписались в российском ЗАГСЕ... Будет она Басюкайте, "щазззз".  

Насчет образования фамилий в литовском (отчасти - и латышском) - не буду спорить, хотя там есть несколько вариантов и я не уверен, что от Басюкайтис будет именно Басюкайтене, а не Басюкене, скажем. Зачем два "родительских" суффикса в фамилии?  
А Басюкайте - это, вроде, женская фамилия без указания семейного статуса, разрешенная с 2003 г.
Но я литовского не знаю...

Comment: Нет, я не литовец, но кое-что о правилах образования литовских фамилий
знаю.Да. пожалуй, Басюкене-вариант.Знаю и то, что тёти из не литовских
ЗАГСов действительно не сильно задумываются над тем, что существуют
какие-то правила в отношении подобных фамилий.Ну, здесь уже сам
носитель должен проинструктировать и настоять на правильном
написании.Если ему, конечно, не всё равно.

Comment: >Нет, я не литовец,    
  
Тогда поиск точной формы женской фамилии - занятие неблагодарное. Там нет четких правил, понятных несведущему. Согласен, что фамилии женщин различаются суффиксами в зависимости от того, дана фамилия по отцу или по мужу (с 2003 г. появился еще и третий вариант - без семейного статуса, на самом деле весьма древний, средневековый), но точная форма внутри  этих разрядов весьма различна в зависимости от происхождения (значения) мужской фамилии. Но это так, к слову.

Comment: Интереснее другое. Вы говорите, что "тети не из литовских загсов" "не сильно задумываются". А на основании чего они должны задумываться? У них есть нормативный документ, никаких вольностей не предусматривающий.   
Было бы наивно требовать от них знания всех тонкостей образования национальных имен, фамилий, а иногда и отчеств. Так что тут трудно чего-то ожидать. Тем более, что заморочек хватает и с "родными" фамилиями. Хотя понять людей, я тоже могу. Вроле бы вопрос как-то решается через консульские службы, но это уже совершенно отдельный разговор.